# Why gradle fails with package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist error?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a fairly complex gradle setup (one parent project and many sub-projects). One of the sub-projects fails with the following error:

`package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist`

I'm using Oracle Java 8 which contains this package (it has been removed in Java 11). I do have Java 11 installed, but it's NOT my active Java version. This is the only sub-project that fails with these errors, while I do have other sub-projects referencing the same packages and succeed to build.

In theory, it's not confused about the Java version.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-u221-oracle
```

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

Using gradle wrapper:

```
$ ./gradlew -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.6.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-11-01 20:42:00 UTC
Revision:     dd870424f9bd8e195d614dc14bb140f43c22da98

Kotlin:       1.3.41
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.14 compiled on March 12 2019
JVM:          1.8.0_221 (Oracle Corporation 25.221-b11)
OS:           Linux 5.0.0-36-generic amd64
```

And even when I `println(org.gradle.internal.jvm.Jvm.current())` it prints Java 8.

Comment: as your other sub-projects do compile, i would recommend you to check the gradle file of the project which is failing, to see if the wrong java version is defined there explicitly

Comment: @sudipn thanks, it's the same everywhere. I even forced the source and target version, but didn't make a difference.

Comment: For the record, the same gradle tasks run successfully on other machines. It's only my machine that fails.

Comment: @sudipn I figured it out, check my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem was that `javac -version` was wrong, it was pointing to Java 11 instead of 8 despite the fact that my `java -version` and `ehco $JAVA_HOME` were both pointing to Java 8.

I ran the gradle task with the `--info` option and carefully read through the output. I found that near the end it says:

```
Compiling with Java command line compiler 'javac'.
Starting process 'command 'javac''. Working directory: /path/to/project Command: javac @/path/to/project/build/tmp/compileJava/java-compiler-args.txt
Successfully started process 'command 'javac''
:project:compileJava (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 2.035 secs.
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

So it occurred to me to check `javac -version` and sure enough, I found `javac 11.0.4`. The reason is that the last time I used `update-alternatives --config java` to change my Java from 8 to 11, I forgot to do `update-alternatives --config javac` as well.

Comment: I had a similar compilation error in Windows 10 Enterprise using ` gradle 7.1.1`, though from command prompt ` java -version` was pointing to ` 1.8.0_351` . I later found that gradle was taking JAVA_HOME configuration which was point to Java 11. Update JAVA_HOME to point to ` Java 8`  resolved the issue